# Invalid MEX-file due to undefined symbol 'start_time'

Tags: c++, matlab, symbols, static-linking, automake

I am attempting to run a complex ice sheet modeling software downloaded from here: [ISSM](https://issm.jpl.nasa.gov/)

After running configuring with automake and compiling properly I'm getting the following error.

> Invalid MEX-file '/home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/TriMesh.mexa64':
>   /home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/libISSMModules.so.0: undefined symbol: start_time
>
> Error in triangle (line 40)
>   [elements,x,y,segments,segmentmarkers]=TriMesh(domainname,riftname,area);
>
> Error in runme (line 11)
>       md=triangle(model,'./DomainOutline.exp',1000);

This is from the following code snippet in `runme.m`:

```
disp('   Step 1: Mesh creation');

%Generate initial uniform mesh (resolution = 20000 m)
md=triangle(model,'./DomainOutline.exp',1000);
```

My thought here was that the `triangle.a` library this is linked against is a static file, thus it should need to be a shared object. However, even after updating the triangle library to be `triangle.so` I was still receiving the same error. At this point I'm all out of ideas. If I am lacking any relevant information please let me know, I'm still relatively new to GNU autotools.

I've tried running the following command with the following output:

> $ nm ./lib/libISSMModules.so.0 | grep 'start_time'
>
> U start_time

A run of the `ldd` command returns the following undefined symbols:

> $ldd -r ./lib/libISSMModules.so.0
>
> undefined symbol: _ZN14ToolkitOptions14toolkitoptionsE (/home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/libISSMCore.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: _ZN8IssmComm4commE    (/home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/libISSMCore.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: _ZN8IssmComm8parallelE    (/home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/libISSMCore.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: _Z9ApiPrintfPKc   (/home/cpmcgrat/Documents/Research/ISSM/issm/trunk/lib/libISSMCore.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: start_time    (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: input_time    (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: Using_Main    (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: interface (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: read_params   (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)
>   undefined symbol: smalloc_stats (./lib/libISSMModules.so.0)

The undefined symbols are either prefixed with a `U` or a `B`.

It is my understanding that `U` means that the symbol is undefined and `B` means the symbol is in an uninitialized section. I am quite unsure of how to fix this however.

Comment: Perhaps your DYNAMIC_LIBRARY_PATH variable is not set correctly.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 where would that be located for modification? Environment, configuration or makefile?

Comment: The environment, usually something like `export DYNAMIC_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/shared/objects1:/path/to/blahblah/` if using BASH. However, I think you'll need to set it prior to starting matlab. Also, if it's already defined, be sure to do `export DYNAMIC_LIBRARY_PATH=/path1:/path2:$DYNAMIC_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I added the paths to `libISSMModules.so.0` and `triangle.a` to `DYNAMIC_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to reconfigure/recompile after setting this variable?

Comment: No need to recompile; it loads the libraries when the program starts. The `*.a` libs are static and need to be given to the linker. Make sure you restart matlab after setting the library path and do so from the same terminal.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I linked *all* of the external libraries in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and re-linked them. However, my undefined symbols are still unresolved. According to other sources, this has something to do with matlab treating all symbols as local symbols. However, this issue appears to be uncommon enough that solutions are impossible to find.

Comment: @asdf I just downloaded the ISSM sources to check it out, and I have to say the compilation is pretty involved (many dependencies!). Now I'm on Windows, so I'm not much help here, but inspecting `externalpackages\triangle` folder you can see that makefile explicitly passes `-DNO_TIMER` flag which I'm guessing is a macro that disables timer-related stuff in code (see `configs\linux64\configure.make`). I'm thinking this related to the missing symbols error you're getting? Anyway you should probably describe all the steps you took to run configure and compile..

Comment: @asdf Sorry! I meant LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your problem but cannot get petsc to build. Regardless of which version, it freezes with "TESTING: configureMPIEXEC from config.packages.MPI(config/BuildSystem/config/packages/MPI.py:145)"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in a position to download and try your code but the symptoms you're describing (the symbol is defined in a library, you're linking to the library, but the symbol is still not found) looks very like a problem with the order in which the libraries are linked.

There are good articles [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) and [here](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html) explaining the problem with link order.  In a nutshell, if the symbol is defined in a library (libA) that is linked before the file or library that requires that symbol (libB), then the symbol will be reported as missing.

Thus the order `libA libB` (where `libB` depends on `libA`) will trigger the error, but `libB libA` will be ok.  If both libraries have mutual dependencies, then either use `libA libB libA` or use `--start-group` and `--end-group` linker flags, where the linker will go round and round the group of files until all unresolved symbols have been found.